# What is The Start Index(Position) of Android ListView , 0 or 1

Tags: android, android-listview

Salam
Simple Question : What is The Start Index(Position) of Android ListView , 0 or 1

```
list.getChildAt(index);
```

Comment: Just like in an array, the start value of a listview is always 0. This is because all elements in the listview are saved as an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**NOTE:** The first index always start with 0.

So `list.getChildAt(index)` will return first child at index 0, next child at index 1 and so on.

However, depending on your start loop, you can fetch starting from any way to fetch any child,

```
for(int i = 0;i< listview.size();i++)
{
  //you get the first child as starting point in a loop
  list.getChildAt(index); //the start index is 0 here.
}

for(int i = 1;i< listview.size();i++)
{
  //you get the second child as starting point in a loop
  list.getChildAt(index); //the start index is 1 here.
}
```

**public View getChildAt (int index)**

*Added in API level 1*

*Returns the view at the specified position in the group.*

**Parameters**

**index**  *the position at which to get the view from*

**Returns**

- *the view at the specified position or null if the position does not exist within the group*